# why there is shadow in ExpanderHeader when Expander is Expanded?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, desktop-application, winui-3

When the Expander is not Expanded

[not Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSqCc.png)

When it Expanded, shadow is appeared, but the Shadow property is null both in ExpanderHeader and ExpanderContent

[Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRMU2.png)

Where can I configure or disable this shadow?

The version of WinUI I am using is:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.0.0-preview3" />
```

update:
I found that as long as the Expander's `CornerRadius` is 0, there is no
shadow in header. But any other value of `CornerRadius` will bring the shadow to the header

[set CornerRadius to 0 and 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aygRP.png)

update2:I found that the shadow seems to come from the button control, if you create button and set there CornerRadius like this:

```
<Button CornerRadius="5,0,0,5" Content="TestButtonShadow" Background="Green"/>
<Button CornerRadius="0,5,5,0" Content="TestButtonShadow" Background="Green"/>
<Button CornerRadius="0,5,0,5" Content="TestButtonShadow" Background="Green"/>
<Button CornerRadius="5,0,5,0" Content="TestButtonShadow" Background="Green"/>
<Button CornerRadius="0,0,5,5" Content="TestButtonShadow" Background="Green"/>
<Button CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" Content="TestButtonShadow" Background="Green"/>
```

and the button will looks like:

[image]

why?